# Using complex calculated values with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two tables, shops and locations.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
$shops = Shop::with('location');
if (Input::has('location')) {
    $shops->whereHas('location', function($q) use ($input) {
        $q->where('name', '=', Input::get('location');
    });
}

return $shops->paginate(10);
```

which is all going fine.

However, I'd like to also include a distance value, and order by it. This basically amounts to creating a calcuated value, which I tried doing like this:

```
$shops->raw('(
    3959 * acos (
        cos ( radians(?) )
   * cos( radians( locations.lat ) )
   * cos( radians( locations.lon ) - radians(?) )
        + sin ( radians(?) )
   * sin( radians( locations.lat ) )
        )
) AS distance
', array(Session::get('latitude'), Session::get('longitude'), Session::get('latitude')));
```

(put before the return value above)

This doesn't do anything - swapping to a whereRaw doesn't work either.

Am I going to have to stop using Eloquent (again!), or is this something Eloquent can deal with?

Comment: 2. You should hook a eloquent event and print the *actual* SQL generated by your function - then you can debug what is occurring.

Comment: This is all the code, I haven't defined the `raw` function specifically. The query doesn't change when using it (probably because it doesn't exist?). Using whereRaw throws an exception.

Comment: I'm thinking aloud that because you are doing a *calculated function* - you probably need to include the `raw()` on the initial call to Shop. So maybe something like `$shops = Show::with('location')->raw(<code>)`

Comment: It seems that `whereRaw` always puts the code after the `WHERE` statement in the SQL, which is logical I guess. I can't work out how to put it before, I think it would work if I could…

Comment: Cam you just use raw()? Also - check this example - you could try select() with DB::raw() - http://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: I think I might have to rewrite the whole thing to use DB instead of Eloquent, which kinda sucks

Comment: mmmm... eloquent should be able to do anything query builder can. You might try asking in the Laravel IRC channel - there are some smart people there. Or wait a bit for an answer until @Antonio Carlos Ribeiro or WereWolf are on next - they tend to be good at this sort of stuff.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some help on IRC this is the way I settled on doing it:

```
// First, specify a manual join onto locations, so the values are available in this query
$shops->join('locations', 'shops.location_id', '=', 'locations.id');

// Second, add the selectRaw (which seems to not have variable binding?)
$shops->selectRaw('(
    3959 * acos (
        cos ( radians('.Session::get('latitude').') )
* cos( radians( locations.lat ) )
* cos( radians( locations.lon ) - radians('.Session::get('longitude').') )
        + sin ( radians('.Session::get('latitude').') )
* sin( radians( locations.lat ) )
        )
) AS distance
');

// select the rest of the variables on shops afterwards to avoid any name collisons
$shops->addSelect('shops.*');
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You need `selectRaw` or `select(DB::raw(...))`, not `whereRaw`
2. You need to join `locations` table to select from it (to attach distance on `Shop` objects) **OR** put that part in the query loading `Location` models (to attach distance to `Location` objects):

   ```
   Shop::with(['location' => function ($q) {
      $q->selectRaw(' *, YOUR_CALC_HERE as distance'); 
      // don't forget to select all with '*'
   }]);
   ```

If you want to order shops by distance, then you definitely need the join.